# Electron + React + Typescript + Visual Studio Code? Debug? Can I debug an electron-react app in visual studio?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

Using some boiler plate code, I am able to get my electron app to work in visual studio code. I can hit the breakpoint for main.js, but not for any of my typescript/React code. I am using webpack to build, but am not married to it. How do I wire up the debugger for the React stuff?

I started with these walk-throughs: [medium.com](https://medium.com/@paulirwin/getting-started-with-electron-and-visual-studio-code-typescript-and-react-36d41b68fadb) and [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html)

Here are my configuration files

launch.js

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "preLaunchTask": "webpack",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            ".",
            "--enable-logging"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

tasks.js

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "webpack",
        "command": "webpack",
        "args": []
    }
]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js",
        //path: __dirname + "/dist"        
    },
    mode: "production" ,

// Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

// When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        // "react": "React",
        // "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it! Found the answer [from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron). Install [Debugger for Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug); change tasks.json to the following, and start one project and then the other. **It works with Typescript, Webpack, and React beautifully!**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [  
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Electron: Main",
        "preLaunchTask": "webpack",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            ".",
            "--enable-logging",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
        ]
    },
      {
          "name": "Electron: Renderer",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9223,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "timeout": 30000
      }
],
"compounds": [
      {
          "name": "Electron: All",
          "configurations": [
              "Electron: Main",
              "Electron: Renderer"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Adding to your answer, I had a similar problem.
I wanted to achieve the ability to debug three instances (main and two entry points).

For that I've created a boilerplate which might come handy https://github.com/ShaharHD/electron-react-webpack-typescript-vscode-debug

Comment: I get below error while trying to debug the renderer process. - ` Uncaught TypeError TypeError: chrome.tabs.query is not a function
    at (program) (chrome-extension://react-developer-tools/build/background.js:190:15)`